How to place two components at a particular center to center distance in KiCad?
I am currently doing a PCB layout in KiCad 8.
I need to place two test point pads such that the center to center distance should be 4.9 mm.
Below image shows my test points.
The center to center distance between TP1 and TP2 should be 4.9 mm.

Can someone please help me how to do it?

Let's assume you have TP1 where you want it already, and you want TP2 to be 4.9 mm away from it. The process is as follows:

Make sure your units are set to mm. (otherwise you'd have to enter the position in the upcoming dialog in mils or inches.)
Select TP2.
Press shift-P. (default hotkey for the "position relative to..." function. This can also be found in the right-click menu if you've modified hotkeys.)
Click the "select reference item" (or something like that--I don't recall the exact wording) button.
Click on TP1.
Make sure the footprint was selected, and not one of its pads or another nearby item. If you have trouble, hold the mouse button while clicking TP1 to get the selection disambiguation menu.
Enter the coordinates you want to move TP2 to, relative to TP1. Example: if you want TP2 to be 4.9 mm below TP1, enter "0" in the X coordinate and "4.9" in the Y coordinate. If you want it to be 4.9 mm to the left of TP1, enter "-4.9" in the X coordinate and "0" in the Y coordinate.
Press the OK/confirm/whatever-it-says button (I don't have KiCad up in front of me, I'm working from memory here).

If you want the footprints to stay this far apart and still be able to move them around as a group, you can select both of them, right-click, and go to the option grouping > group items. Now they'll move and rotate together unless you ungroup them or enter the group to move them individually.


Place them on top of each other, if one of them is placed, or can be placed on the grid place that one first, and the other to match.
Then use the move exactly command (the default hotkey I believe is SHIFT+M but you can find yours by listing hotkeys) to move only one of them the separation that you need.


You can then either lock them in place using L, or you can make them a group. 
